# Analogue of Lipschitz continuity of $W^{1,\infty}$ for Hölder continuity and Sobolev-Slobodeckij spaces

Tags: measure-theory, sobolev-spaces, function-spaces

A function $u : U \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is an element of the Hölder space $C^{\alpha}(U)$ if

- $\sup\limits_{x \in U} |u(x)| < \infty$
- $\sup\limits_{x,y \in U} \dfrac{|u(x) - u(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} < \infty$

A function $u : U \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is an element of the fractional Sobolev space $W^{\alpha,\infty}(U)$ if

- $\mathrm{esssup}_{x \in U} |u(x)| < \infty$
- $\mathrm{esssup}_{x,y \in U} \dfrac{|u(x) - u(y)|}{|x-y|^\alpha} < \infty$

Here, $\mathrm{esssup}$ denotes the essentially supremum.

Clearly, $C^\alpha(U)$ is a subspace of $W^{\alpha,\infty}(U)$. Does the converse statement hold, that is, $W^{\alpha,\infty}(U)$ is a subspace of $C^\alpha(U)$?

The claim is true if $\alpha = 1$ when $U$ has sufficient boundary regularity, in which case we just deal with Rademacher's theorem: a function is Lipschitz continuous if and only if it is essentially bounded with essentially bounded derivatives.

The generalization is claimed in the [Encyclopedia of Math](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Lipschitz_condition) but no reference is given.

Does there exist a short proof or an explicit reference in the literature (paper, textbook)?

Comment: Technically one has to identify functions that agree a.e. before one gets the identity between $C^\alpha(U)$ and $W^{\alpha,\infty}(U)$ (even in the $\alpha=1$ case), but yes, this statement is true.  Given $u \in W^{\alpha,\infty}(U)$, standard mollifiers $u * \varphi_\varepsilon$ will be uniformly bounded in $C^\alpha(U)$ and converge uniformly to a limit $\tilde u \in C^\alpha(U)$ that is equal a.e. to $u$.

Comment: Another way to get this without any boundary regularity is to note that there exists a set of full measure $A$ on which the suprema are finite. The function $u$ is then continuous on $A$. Since $U$ is open, $A$ is dense in $U$ and $u$ has a unique continuous extension to $U$ that satisfies the required properties.

Comment: @JeanVanSchaftingen: thanks, but it is not obvious that you get such a set $A$. Let me explain: the function $f(x,y) = |u(x)-u(y)| \cdot |x-y|^{-\alpha}$ is locally integrable over $U \times U$ and hence there exists a dense subset $B \subseteq U \times U$ over which (a representative of) $f$ is bounded. The existence of $A$ is not immediately clear. Is there some handwaving to find it?